# What should I put to return one to many list in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I tried to return a object class, however the attempt is failed.

```
public class tbl_Product
{     
    public tbl_Product()
    {
        tbl_ProductDescription = new HashSet<tbl_ProductDescription>();
        tbl_ProductPricing = new HashSet<tbl_ProductPricing>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }      
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Product")]
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_ProductPricing> tbl_ProductPricing { get; set; }
 }
```

---

Below is my WebAPI function during return:

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<ActionResult<ICollection<tbl_Product>>> GetProductList()
{
    var result = _context.tbl_Product
        .Include(a => a.tbl_ProductPricing).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

---

However, I got this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.tbl_Product>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Model.tbl_Product>>>'
```

May I know what's the return type should I put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection<tbl_Product>>> GetProductList()
{
    return Ok(await _context.tbl_Product.Include(a => a.tbl_ProductPricing).ToListAsync());
}
```

The returned instance must match the type specified in the method signature. In your case you are specifying that the return type will be `Task<ActionResult<ICollection<tbl_Product>>>` so it must 1) return a Task and 2) the task must resolve an instance of `ActionResult<ICollection<tbl_Product>>` and 3) that ActionResult must have the content that implements `ICollection<tbl_Product>`.

---

*I am assuming you are using .net core and referring to [`ActionResult<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2)*